# How to filter images by titles in Lightroom library

Tags: adobe-lightroom

The custom filter panel for Lightroom library does not seem to have an option to filter pictures by "title" - I can only see "date", "file type", "camera", etc. Is there any way I can filter my own collection through the metadata that are not already specified in the panel?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is yes and no.

In the library panel, you can click on metadata, and you will see a number of columns that you can use to filter your images. If you click on the upper right corner of one of these columns, you get a drop down screen that allows you to "Add Column."
[image]

Once you have added that new column, click on the column title (which will be "None") and you will see a drop down menu that shows a number of other metadata options that you can use for filtering.  Unfortunately, none of the choices is "title."

[image]

You can, however, search on the title or any word in a searchable field in your image.  If you click on the "Text" item at the top of the Library page, it brings up a search option, and you can search either on "Any Searchable Field" or other options (including Title) accessible via the arrows at the right of that "Any Searchable Field" field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any plugins that might help add a custom filter to the panel?

Comment: I would bet there are, but I am pretty new with Lightroom myself, and haven't ever tried any plug-ins for the program.  Probably worth googling...